# how to change an error message?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

please help solve the problem.
is a form of:
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wTMv3/694/)

Form is validated using the plugin. I created an additional method of verification:

```
$.validator.addMethod("checkFileSize",function(value) {
    // check filesize
    return false;
}, "wrong filesize");
```

until it returns false. why should show error messages may be:

> wrong filesize

but the error message is displayed:

> wrong format

please help display an error message:

> wrong filesize

Answer (score 1):

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/wTMv3/695/

messages object was overriding attachment message, I removed it

```
messages: {
    message_new: "enter message",
    name_new: "enter name",
    email_new: "enter email",
    phone_new: "enter phone"
}
```

Comment: @stackov1, with `return true`, there is not supposed to be any error message because `true` means it *passed* validation!